# Insert into Temp Table from SQL Dynamic Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to insert the result of the sql dynamic into a temp table but i am getting a syntax error. I have researched and i am not able to figure what i am doing wrong here

```
  DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME([month]) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Month] FROM MyTable) AS [Month]
 order by [month]

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT Mem_Name, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM MyTable   into MyTest
    PIVOT(SUM(Amount) 
          FOR Month IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable' 
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Comment: You have plenty enough rep to know that when you get an error you should share the error message. And provide some details so others might be able to help. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: Where is your temptable? Your not insert anything in this script. And what is your error? That would help alot

Comment: Which statement has the syntax error and what character is the error "near"?

Comment: i have updated my code to show where i was trying to insert into MyTest table

Comment: it is syntax error as i mentioned in my post and it is exactly saying "Incorrect syntax near 'myTest'."

Comment: See having the actual error message gives us some insight. Just saying I have an error is pretty much useless. You have the INTO and FROM backwards. Checkout the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all what i had to do is add this:
' into ##myTempTable

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') + QUOTENAME([month]) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Month] FROM MyTable) AS [Month]
 order by [month]

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT Mem_Name, ' + @ColumnName + ' into ##myTempTable 
    FROM MyTable   
    PIVOT(SUM(Amount) 
          FOR Month IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable' 
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```